# typescript union type with objects throw warning

Tags: typescript

I'm working with a simple feature related to display some messages, the basic message structure is the same, but there's a data field matching each type of messages with different structure. The rough example is like the following.

```
type MessageBase = {
  id: number;
  data: B | C;
};

type B = {
  title: string;
  body: string;
};

type C = {
  url: string;
};

const message: MessageBase = {
  id: 1,
  data: {
    body: "Hello",
    title: "World",
  },
};
// all above code work fine
```

I thought it'll be like some simple union, data could be either type B or type C, great!

```
type Demo = string | number
const demo: Demo = 'Hello' // demo could be either string or number
```

But when I try to use the type in actual components, ts throws a warning saying

```
const { title } = message.data;
Property 'title' does not exist on type 'B | C'
```

Could anyone help pointing out where did I go wrong? Any suggestions would help, thank you guys in advanced!

Comment: TypeScript doesn't let you index into a value if it's not sure that the index is present.  Since there might or might not be a `title` property in a value of type `B | C` this isn't safe.  See the answers to the linked questions for ways to proceed.

Comment: noted, makes sense. I'll check out the linked question. Thank you!